# comparing time portion of POSIXct in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, posix, posixct

I have a `data.frame` that contains a bunch of `POSIXct` dates:

```
df <- data.frame(dte=as.POSIXct(c("2001-02-03 14:30:00",
  "2001-02-04 9:30:00", "2001-02-05 10:30:00")), a=1:3)
```

I would like to extract the part of the `df` that has the time portion greater than 9:15 AM and less than 5:25 PM.  I could extract the components of hour and minute separately and write a comparison but i thought there might be a more elegant way of doing it.  Can anyone make a suggestion?

My current method would be:

```
df <- subset(df,
  (as.numeric(format(dte, "%H")) >  9 & as.numeric(format(dte, "%M")) > 15) |
  (as.numeric(format(dte, "%H")) < 17 & as.numeric(format(dte, "%M")) < 25))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use xts instead of a data.frame.

```
df <- data.frame(dte=as.POSIXct(c("2001-02-03 14:30:00",
  "2001-02-04 9:30:00", "2001-02-05 10:30:00")), a=1:3)
library(xts)
x <- xts(df$a, df$dte)
x["T09:15/T17:25"]  # returns everything (in your example)
x["T10:15/T14:25"]  # returns the correct subset
```

Comment: i currently use `zoo` for all my time series stuff. could you suggest why it would be useful to switch to `xts`? i read the documentation but it's pretty abstract

Comment: The subsetting alone is worth the switch. Zoo is generic ("ordered observations"), xts is the same idea on steroids for financial data.

Comment: very good, thank you! i will dig in to the xts documentation as i'm not very familiar with it.  it reminds me of `data.table` from your comments.

Comment: @Alex: `data.table` is more like a data.frame.  xts objects are like zoo objects (a matrix with an index attribute).  xts it makes it very easy to do what you asked in your question. It's also optimized for speed on large data sets (e.g. merging two series of several million observations takes < 1 second).

Comment: can i ask how you knew to write things as "T09:15" for example? would you happen to have a reference i could take a look at or is this in the `xts` documentation? i saw that you can subset things in this manner but how do you know to put the T in front of the time?

Comment: the thing that has me confused: "To identify a particular hour, say all observations in the eighth hour on
January 1, 2007, one would likewise need to include the full year, month and
day - e.g. \2007-01-01 08."

Comment: @Alex: I knew about it because I helped write it.  An example is given in `?.parseISO8601`, which (I admit) is buried deep in the xts documentation.  I'm not sure what you're quoting, but that will only return times in the 8:00 hour on 2007-01-01.  The "leading T" subsetting gets a time range across multiple days.

Comment: i was just quoting the xts documentation which says that to identify all observations of a particular month, you also need to specify the year, for example. that is why i was impressed that you knew how to do this in such a slick way.

Comment: @Alex: Ah, I see.  A member of SO sent me a xts-FAQ draft and this is included in it, so it will soon be documented there. ;)

Comment: fantastic - thank you!  could you tell me how to do other subsetting tricks like all the data between certain months for all years, or all day for certain days for all months and years?

Comment: @Alex: That's a great question and the answer is 'yes'.  Ask it via another question and I'll answer. :)