# How to select time range during weekdays and associated data on the next column

Tags: r, range

Here is an example of a subset data in .csv files. There are three columns with no header. The first column represents the date/time and the second column is load [kw] and the third column is 1= weekday, 0 = weekends/ holiday.

```
9/9/2010 3:00   153.94  1
9/9/2010 3:15   148.46  1
```

I would like to program in R, so that it selects the first and second column within time ranges from 10:00 to 20:00 for all weekdays (when the third column is 1) within a month of September and do not know what's the best and most efficient way to code.

```
code dt <- read.csv("file", header = F, sep=",") 

#Select a column with weekday designation = 1, weekend or holiday = 0 

y <- data.frame(dt[,3]) 

#Select a column with timestamps and loads 

x <- data.frame(dt[,1:2]) 
t <- data.frame(dt[,1]) 

#convert timestamps into readable format 

s <- strptime("9/1/2010 0:00", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") 
e <- strptime("9/30/2010 23:45", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") 
range <- seq(s,e, by = "min") 
df <- data.frame(range)
```

Comment: What have you tried?  It sounds like you're asking us to write your code for you.  Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  It will make it much easier to answer your questions.

Comment: Somehow I kept having a problem posting my code. Here is what I have so far. `code` dt <- read.csv("file", header = F, sep=",")
  
  #Select a column with weekday designation = 1, weekend or holiday = 0
  y <- data.frame(dt[,3])
  #Select a column with timestamps and loads
  x <- data.frame(dt[,1:2])
  t <- data.frame(dt[,1])
  
  #convert timestamps into readable format
  
  s <- strptime("9/1/2010 0:00", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
  e <- strptime("9/30/2010 23:45", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
  range <- seq(s,e, by = "min")                
  df <- data.frame(range)

Comment: Related to [comparing time portion of POSIXct in R](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11853524/271616).

Answer (score 2):

OP ask for "best and efficient way to code" this without showing "inefficient code", so @Justin is right.

It's seems that the OP is new to R (and it's officially [the summer of love](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/)) so I give it a try and I have a solution (not sure about efficiency..)

```
index <- c("9/9/2010 19:00", "9/9/2010 21:15", "10/9/2010 11:00", "3/10/2010 10:30")
index <- as.POSIXct(index, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(Date = index, load = rnorm(4, mean = 120, sd = 10), weeks = c(0, 1, 1, 1))

## Data
##                  Date   load weeks
## 1 2010-09-09 19:00:00 113.74     0
## 2 2010-09-09 21:15:00 121.84     1
## 3 2010-09-10 11:00:00 111.64     1
## 4 2010-10-03 10:30:00 135.95     1


cond <- expression(format(Date, "%H:%M") < "20:00" & 
                   format(Date, "%H:%M") > "10:00" & 
                   weeks == 1 & 
                   format(Date, "%m") == "09")

subset(Data, eval(cond))
##                  Date   load weeks
## 3 2010-09-10 11:00:00 111.64     1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry I just started using R and do not want to make a fool of myself by posting my codes. I am really bad at this.